# WPF Custom TextWrapping

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

I'm using AvalonEdit for an editing control and I wanted to customize the word wrapping functionality. Right now by default, word wrapping line breaks are detected for spaces. I wanted it to do wrapping based on commas as well.

Example: 
**Hello there,testing**

If the width of the control isn't long enough, this would wrap to be
**Hello

there,testing**

However, if the control width is even smaller, the above example would wrap to
**Hello

there,test

ing**

I'm trying to avoid this situation by having it handle the comma as well.

I looked at AvalonEdit and it uses the standard `System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextFormatter` class. The `TextFormatter` has `TextParagraphProperties` which contains `TextWrapping`. It doesn't seem like Microsoft is allowing us to customize `TextWrapping`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the following?

```
TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"
```